# Ошибка при подключение к Windows Server по SSH c#

Tags: c#, windows, сервер, ssh

Ошибка при подключение к Windows Server по SSH

Код:

```
using Renci.SshNet;

string user = "Администратор";
string pass = "********";
string host = "*********";

        using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
        {
            //Start the connection
            client.Connect();
            var output = client.RunCommand("echo test");
            client.Disconnect();
            Console.WriteLine(output.Result);
        }
```

Ошибка:

```
Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера
```

Кто знает как решить данную ошибку, возможно я что-то неправильно делаю?

Comment: Файервол, удалённые подключения?

Comment: @Anatol Да, нужно сделать программу, которая заходит на сервер и запускает exe файл

Comment: А через PuTTY подключается?

Comment: @Alex78191 Нет(

Comment: Какой SSH сервер стоит? Через localhost подключается?

Comment: На сервере должен быть запущен ssh-сервер, в windows нет стандартных встроенных служб для работы с ssh.

Comment: Зачем нужен SSH, если есть WinRS/WinRM? https://serverfault.com/questions/429426/how-can-i-connect-to-a-windows-server-using-a-command-line-interface-cli

Comment: @fangry, спецом для вас перевел написаное на Phyton в C#, а вы удалили вопрос.

Comment: @СергейИгнахин извините, все почему-то взбесились, вот я и удалил. Могу восстановить, если не удалили перевод

Comment: @fangry, восстановите. Перевод остался.

Comment: @СергейИгнахин восстановил https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/1204624?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Все ниже перечисленное актуально только если вы имеете административные права на сервере. Если таких прав у вас нет, то ответ короткий - удаленное управление  и запуск произвольных программ невозможны.**

В стандартную поставку Windows не входят сервисы для работы с SSH, поэтому вам необходимо самостоятельно установить и настроить любой удобный удобный для вас сторонний SSH-сервер, благо выбор есть.

Из стандартных средств удаленного управления есть следующее:

- **Telnet** - древний и небезопасный, поэтому по умолчанию выключен во всех версиях Windows. Для работы с ним придется его включать руками (Панель управления\Программы\Программы и компоненты => Включение или отключение компонентов Windows). **Доступно на всех версиях Windows. Возможно программное управление.**
- **MMC** (Microsoft Management Console) - позволяет выполнять практически все административные задачи кроме интерактивного запуска программ. Фоновый запуск возможен путем настройки заданий в планировщике задач. **Доступно начиная с  Windows 2000. Программное управление и запуск произвольных программ невозможны.**
- **WMI** (Windows Management Instrumentation) - является основным средством централизованного управления в Windows. Позволяет получать исчерпывающую информацию о системе и управлять любыми системными параметрами. Удобство на любителя, но средство действительно мощное, поэтому удаленное взаимодействие с помощью WMI по-умолчанию отключено в целях безопасности. Потребуется некоторая настройка. **Доступно начиная с  Windows 2000. Возможно программное управление. Запуск произвольных программ непосредственно невозможен**
- **WinRM + WinRS**  (Windows Remote Management, Windows Remote Shell) - Удаленная консоль. Позволяет то же что и локальная консоль. В основе WMI, весь трафик шифруется, аутентификация Kerberos. Идеально для работы в домене, для автономного использования потребуется дополнительная настройка безопасности. В любом случае требуется предварительная настройка сервера для работы. **Доступно начиная с  Windows Server 2008. Возможно программное управление.**
- **RDP** (Remote Desktop Protocol) - Предназначен исключительно для интерактивной работы с удаленным сервером. **Доступно начиная с  Windows 2000. Программное управление и запуск произвольных программ невозможны.**

Про настройку удаленного управления можно почитать [тут](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh921475(v=ws.11).aspx). Или задать вопрос по конкретной проблеме с конкретным вариантом, т.к. каждый из них имеет свои особенности и тянет на отдельную статью.